# How to perform Estimote iBeacon Account Login and Logout in iPhone application programatically?

Tags: ios, authentication, ibeacon, estimote

I am working on beacons based application. And I am using Estimote beacons. I have one problem in which I am not able to show login screen of estimote account in my iphone application like this:

When I am running sample code of Estimote SDK then to find temperature this popup is showing.

[image]

So, for login on estimote account in iPhone application by this screen, what should I do ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Dennis I have to show this screen as shown in Estimote application which I downloaded from iTunes.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, and explain what does not work.

Comment: @Dennis And If you are working on Estimote SDK then you can understand what exactly issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to connect to Estimote Beacons, you do not use Estimote Account credentials, but rather your app ID and API token, that have to be provided in the app. It's explained right here: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203607313-What-are-App-ID-and-App-Token-and-what-do-I-need-them-for-

Cheers.